# 2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:13:in `on_complete': Bad Authentication data. (Twitter::Error::BadRequest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, faraday

Simply put, I'm attempting to post a tweet using these pieces of ruby code:

```
require 'Twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
config.consumer_key        = "my_key"
config.consumer_secret     = "my_secret_key"
config.access_token        = "my_token"
config.access_token_secret = "my_secret_token"
end

client.update("I'm tweeting with a @gem!")
```

I'm using 64-bit ruby 2.3.0 with the appropriate 64-bit dev kit on Windows 10.

However, a `on_complete': Bad Authentication data. (Twitter::Error::BadRequest) appears like so:

```
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:13:in `on_complete': Bad Authentication data. (Twitter::Error::BadRequest)
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:9:in `block in call'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:61:in `on_complete'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/request/multipart.rb:14:in `call'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/request/multipart_with_file.rb:21:in `call'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/faraday-0.11.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:177:in `post'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/request.rb:33:in `perform'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:50:in `perform_request'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:72:in `perform_request_with_object'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/utils.rb:64:in `perform_post_with_object'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib/twitter/rest/tweets.rb:158:in `update!'
from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-6.1.0/lib                                                                        /twitter/rest/tweets.rb:128:in `update'
from om_tweet.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance for your time and advice!

Comment: Have you enabled "write" permissions for your app, on the twitter account?

Comment: Yes, permissions are currently set to read, write, and direct messages.

Comment: Are you able to read tweets? (Is the key/secret/token definitely right?)

Comment: I'm closing this thread. The key/secret/token had whitespace in them after I pasted them into my code. I appreciate your help, Tom! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After copy/pasting the keys into their appropriate lines, whitespace was found to be present in the keys. Deleting the whitespace allowed the ruby file to function as designed. Thanks and kudos to Tom Lord for help and critique!